# Посчитать количество чётных чисел в списке

Tags: c#

Есть файл с 50 числами, нужно посчитать количество чётных. Если я правильно понимаю, чтобы это сделать надо как-то обратиться к элементам списка, но как это сделать?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> st = new List<string>();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C: \\Users\\User\\Desktop\\файлы\\chisla.txt");
        while (true)
        {
            string s = sr.ReadLine();
            if (s == null) break;
            st.Add(s); 
        }
        sr.Close();
        foreach (string spisok in st)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(spisok);
        }
```

Comment: int x = int.Parse( mystring );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например:

```
var st = new List<int>();
using (var sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\файлы\chisla.txt"))
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        var s = sr.ReadLine();
        st.Add(int.Parse(s)); // тут ещё можно добавить проверку на то, что это действительно число, или использовать TryParse 
    }
}

// тут считаем кол-во четных чисел
var count = st.Count(item => (item & 1) == 0);
```

Это `(item & 1) == 0` условие проверяет четное оно или нет, используя побитовые операции, вместо этого можно использовать `item % 2 == 0`.